# microdata not displaying in google search results

Tags: microdata, schema.org

I have a "Review-aggregate" microdata snippet in my site, and google has cached it, but it is not appearing in the google search results with the rating stars.

The URL that has the microdata in is:

http://www.rnsalert.com/

And here is the snippet:

```
<div class="ui-corner-bottom" id="micro-data-reviews" itemscope="" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Review-aggregate">

<span itemprop="itemreviewed">RNSalert</span> is rated 
<span itemprop="rating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Rating">
<span itemprop="average">9.0</span>
out of <span itemprop="best">10</span>
</span>
based on <a href="http://www.trustpilot.co.uk/review/rnsalert.com" target="_blank"><span itemprop="votes">16</span> independent ratings</a>.

</div>
```

Using Google's structured data test tool, it shows that the microdata is being parsed correctly...

http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.rnsalert.com%2F&html=

Yet the google search results aren't showing it. The page has been cached.

Search google for "RNS alert" and you will get the page listed as the first organic result.

Any thoughts?

Many thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

Google should recognise all types defined in schema.org, but it supports rich snippets in the search results for these content types only:

- Reviews
- People
- Products
- Businesses and organizations
- Recipes
- Events
- Music

Source:

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99170&topic=1088472&ctx=topic

Also, it may take a while before you're able to see them in the search results - maybe even days.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The meta data is still not showing. it's definitely valid markup :(

Comment: Even long indexed snippets will not show in sezrch results. We have the same issue and our snippets are over 1 year long now, are valid and tested in search console that show their preview, yet aggregate reating is showing in search results only for selected products

Answer (score 0):

I'm 95% sure that for your rating/review stars to appear in Google's web results you must also setup Google authorship with the site/page.
6+ months ago this step wasn't required.

Comment: I thought the authorship was just required for the blog image photos you see next to a lot of people's blogs?

Answer (score 0):

Your page contains microdata for a review aggregate, but it is not related to a product or item.

Check the examples here https://schema.org/AggregateRating

The aggregate needs to be within the scope of another item:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Restaurant">
  <span itemprop="name">GreatFood</span>
  <div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
    <span itemprop="ratingValue">4</span> stars -
based on <span itemprop="reviewCount">250</span> reviews
  </div>
  <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
    <span itemprop="streetAddress">1901 Lemur Ave</span>
    <span itemprop="addressLocality">Sunnyvale</span>,
<span itemprop="addressRegion">CA</span> <span itemprop="postalCode">94086</span>
  </div>
  <span itemprop="telephone">(408) 714-1489</span>
  <a itemprop="url" href="http://www.dishdash.com">www.greatfood.com</a>
  Hours:
  <meta itemprop="openingHours" content="Mo-Sa 11:00-14:30">Mon-Sat 11am - 2:30pm
  <meta itemprop="openingHours" content="Mo-Th 17:00-21:30">Mon-Thu 5pm - 9:30pm
  <meta itemprop="openingHours" content="Fr-Sa 17:00-22:00">Fri-Sat 5pm - 10:00pm
  Categories:
  <span itemprop="servesCuisine">
Middle Eastern
  </span>,
  <span itemprop="servesCuisine">
Mediterranean
  </span>
  Price Range: <span itemprop="priceRange">$$</span>
  Takes Reservations: Yes
</div>
```

Unfortunately, just because you put something on your site doesn't mean that Google has to show it in their search results.

I would assume that they need to have a certain amount of trust in your site before anything will show. If not then everyone would just mark their own products/posts with 5 stars so it looks good in a search listing page.

In my experience, it is a lot easier to get rating stars in listings when your site contains votes for other people's products rater than your own.

Answer (score 0):

[Google help](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6398748?__RICH_CARD_BLUE_LINKS):

> - **The search preview is approximate.**
>
>   Real Google Search results for your data might look different.
> - **The search preview is illustrative.**
>
>   We do not guarantee that the content you preview will be displayed in Search results. Your content will likely appear in Search results for relevant queries, but that content must first pass through our systems to be appropriately indexed and ranked before it appears in actual Search results. We reserve the right to filter out any results at our discretion if it violates our quality guidelines. Finally, any preview tool URL for your content is only valid for a limited duration (e.g. weeks).